# laravel валидация массива файлов

Tags: php, laravel, валидация

Есть объект item, у которого есть массив объектов attachment, в котором хранятся картинки. У каждой картинки есть свое представление в базе данных и у них есть свойство type(1, 2, 3, 4).
Как задать разные правила валидации к картинкам с разными типами? К примеру, картинки с типами 2 и 4 должны быть required.

На данный момент `'item.attachment' => required'` работает для картинок со всеми типами, но
`'item.attachment.*' => required_if:type,==,2'` уже не работает. Можно ли как-то поставить условия валидации для картинки, относительно значения ее атрибута?

Comment: 1. `==` нужно убрать: `required_if:type,2` 2. Валидировать можно кастомно, в мане есть примеры [через After Validation Hook](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#adding-after-hooks-to-form-requests) или [через Complex Conditional Array Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#complex-conditional-array-validation)

Comment: Да, добавил в валидатор кастомный метод

Comment: Если вы решили проблему, напишите ее решение в виде ответа, затем примите его. Тут так принято